# How to run validation on hitting the submit button for exposed views filters. Currently it runs on first page load

Tags: views, forms

I am trying to add validation errors to exposed views filters (drop down lists) in block region. However, my validation error runs on the first page load before I hit apply button.

Also the validation doesn't run on hitting the apply button as the validation function has already been run on first page upload. I have also tried 'views->advance->views exposed forms->input required, but no luck.

I think its a known bug in exposed views filters.I have been trying to sort this issue for last three days and went thorough several discussion forums. I will be grateful if anyone can share a patch or guideline through which I can have my validation function run only when apply/submit button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_forms_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'views_exposed_form':{
        $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_forms_views_exposed_form_validate';
        break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Validate views exposed filters in the block region.
 */
function custom_forms_views_exposed_form_validate ($form, &$form_state){
    $value = $form_state['values']['field_number_of_bedrooms_value'];
    if ($value == "Select any"){
        form_set_error ('field_number_of_bedrooms_value', t('You must select valid numbers of bedrooms.'));
    }
}
```

Note:  The value 'Select any' is a node field value with no results. I created it to be used as a default value that displays no results on first page load. I even changed the default value to '-Any-' from views interface, but no success. All the fields are set to 'Required' and the exposed form also has 'Reset' button